# Defined behavior, passing character to printf("%02X"

Tags: c, printf, undefined

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063039/mac-address-printing), where the OP was having issues printing the hexadecimal value of a variable.  I believe the problem can be summed by the [following code](http://www.ideone.com/MOega):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char signedChar = 0xf0;

    printf("Signed\n”);
    printf(“Raw: %02X\n”, signedChar);
    printf(“Masked: %02X\n”, signedChar &0xff);
    printf(“Cast: %02X\n", (unsigned char)signedChar);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Signed
Raw: FFFFFFF0
Masked: F0
Cast: F0
```

The format string used for each of the prints is `%02X`, which I’ve always interpreted as ‘print the supplied `int` as a hexadecimal value with at least two digits’.

The first case passes the signedCharacter as a parameter and prints out the wrong value (because the other three bytes of the `int` have all of their bits set).

The second case gets around this problem, by applying a bit mask (`0xFF`) against the value to remove all but the least significant byte, where the `char` is stored.  Should this work?  Surely: `signedChar == signedChar & 0xFF`?

The third case gets around the problem by casting the character to an `unsigned char` (which seems to clear the top three bytes?).

For each of the three cases above, can anybody tell me if the behavior defined? How/Where?

Comment: Integer types smaller than `int` get promoted to `int` when passed to printf.

Comment: Since the underlaying bit representation of numbers is not defined in the C standard, the exact output is unspecified.

Comment: @Paul R: So in the second case, will the promotion always take place before the bitmask is applied?  Or can it occur after in which the mask would have no effect?

Comment: The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined, by the way. If you want a signed character, use `signed char`.

Comment: @unwind: really?  I've always assumed that variables were signed by default unless you specified otherwise.  Is it the same for integers?

Comment: @forsavir: `char` is special - it is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char` and it may be either signed or unsigned according to your compiler (and may be even different with a given compiler depending on compiler switches).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this behavior is completely defined by c standard. After all it depends on binary representation of signed values. I will just describe how it's likely to work.

```
printf(“Raw: %02X\n”, signedChar);
```

`(char)0xf0` which can be written as `(char)-16` is converted to `(int)-16` its hex representation is `0xfffffff0`.

```
printf(“Masked: %02X\n”, signedChar &0xff);
```

`0xff` is of type `int` so before calculating `&`, `signedChar` is converted to `(int)-16`.
`((int)-16) & ((int)0xff)` == `(int)0x000000f0`.

```
printf(“Cast: %02X\n", (unsigned char)signedChar);
```

`(unsigned char)0xf0` which can be written as `(unsigned char)240` is converted to `(unsigned int)240` as hex it's `0x000000f0`

Comment: `(unsigned char)240` gets converted to `(int)240` as per 6.3.1.1:2 in the C99 standard: “If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int”

Comment: And which way is better/faster if I only want to print 2 symbols? Masked or cast?