# Issues printing a MAC address

Tags: c, ioctl

A MAC address is parsed into an array of bytes (`macaddr`). The bytes are
printed with `printf()` one after another. The bytes are supposed to look as
pairs of hexadecimal characters. But some of them are padded with `f`
characters.

For example, for `macaddr[3]` it prints `'ffffffcc'` rather than `'cc'`, i.e.
4 bytes instead of single byte. The rest of the array items are printed
correctly (`macaddr[0]` = `00`, `macaddr[1]` = `AA`, `macaddr[2]` = `BB`,
etc.)

What's the problem?
Please help me to figure out what's wrong with the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <net/if.h> // struct ifconf
#include <errno.h>
#include <libnet.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getmacaddr() ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getmacaddr();    
}

int getmacaddr()
{
    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq *ifr;
    int sfd;
    int i;
    int devnums;
    char macaddr[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];

    ifc.ifc_req = NULL;

    sfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sfd == -1)
    {
        perror("socket : ");
        return -1;
    }

    // get ifc.ifc_len
    if(ioctl(sfd,SIOCGIFCONF,&ifc) == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl - SIOCGIFCONF : ");
        return -1;
    }
    devnums = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);

    // malloc ifc.ifc_buf and get IFCONF list
    ifc.ifc_buf = malloc(ifc.ifc_len);
    memset(ifc.ifc_buf,0x0,ifc.ifc_len);

    if(ioctl(sfd,SIOCGIFCONF,&ifc) == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl - SIOCGIFCONF : ");
        return -1;
    }


    for(i = 0; i < devnums; i++,ifc.ifc_req++)
    {
        // idfy dev
        if( strcmp(ifc.ifc_req->ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,"lo") && ifc.ifc_req->ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name != 0)
        {
            ifr = ifc.ifc_req;

            // IP address
            struct sockaddr_in *a = (struct sockaddr_in *) &ifr->ifr_addr;
            printf("%s",inet_ntoa(a->sin_addr));
            printf("\n");

            //get IFHWADDR
            if(ioctl(sfd,SIOCGIFHWADDR,ifr) == -1)
            {
                perror("ioctl - SIOCGIFHWADDR : ");
                return -1;
            }            
        }
    }

    memcpy(macaddr,ifr->ifr_hwaddr.sa_data,sizeof(macaddr));
    for(i = 0; i < ETHER_ADDR_LEN; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x ",macaddr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    close(sfd);
    //    free(ifc.ifc_buf);   <- ?? error

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've replaced the following line:

```
printf("%02x ",macaddr[i]);
```

with

```
printf("%02x ", (macaddr[i] & 0xff));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)macaddr[i] & 0xff);
```

We specify the *minimum* field width in the format string. So to make sure that the value will look exactly as a single byte, you can leave only the first 16 bits by applying a bit mask.

Comment: I solved the problem, but I still curious why macaddr[3] print 'ffffffcc'. anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @black, hmm, there should be another issue. Could you update your post with the new code?

Comment: I just replaced [printf("%02x ",macaddr[i]);] with [printf("%02x ", (macaddr[i] & 0xff));]. remainder is same.

Comment: @black, that's really strange. I hope you don't mind I've edited your post. Original text is available in older revisions, if you find the changes wrong.

Comment: With the previous version I could reproduce the issue (it printed `08 ffffffed ffffffb9 25 ffffffe9 56` on my local machine). After applying the mask, it prints `08 ed b9 25 e9 56`.

Comment: I appreciate your edit. my post get better sentence. you are so kind. very very thank you!!

Comment: oh, I find to solve it!! It's signed vs unsigned problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063039/mac-address-printing) It's all thanks to you. because my english is very poor, so I don't know what I search word. But after your rewrite, I can know search word to solving for this problem. thanks!

Comment: @black, heh, signedness. Indeed.